# Access property on dynamic TypeScript Interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm currently in the process of migrating a nuxt application with Vuex from JS to TS. I'm starting with one of ou Vuex modules. The thing is that we use a library we wrote at our company and that is used in other projects (can't touch it or migrate it to TS...) to generate some base state, getters, setters, actions and mutations for each module given a certain entity. This library is written is JS with no types available so I'm working on some shims to get some typings in my project. Let me walk you through the whole workflow before I explain my problem.

The library exports a `createEntity` function that takes a String and returns an object that looks like this:

```js
       {
        path,                 //The name of the module
        mutationPrefix,       //path.uppercase()
        actionPrefix,         //path
        singleSchema,         //some normalizr stuff
        multipleSchema,       //some normalizr stuff
        storeKey: 'entities', //the default name for the key in the store
       }
```

We then use the Entity that has been returned to generate the baseState/baseMutations/baseGetters/baseActions of this store module (these are basic CRUD operations on a given entity).

For the module I'm working on (the first I'm migrating to TS), the `state.ts` file looks like this

```js
    import { createState } from '@kissmylabs/vuex-entitystore'
    import { Provider } from '~/types/models/Provider'
    import { provider } from './entities' // The entity created by our createEntity() library function

    export const baseCreateForm = (): Provider => ({
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      // ... some other form fields
    })

    export const getBaseState = () => ({
      ...createState(provider), // The state created by our createState() library function
      pagination: {
        total: 0,
      },
      createForm: baseCreateForm(),
      isImpersonating: false,
    })

    export default getBaseState
```

So I'm trying to implement types for my state, using some TS Interfaces. My interface BaseState (the return type of my `createState()` library function) looks like this

```js
  interface BaseState {
    storeKey: {
      byId: any,
      allIds: Array<number>,
      active: Array<any>,
      deleted: Array<any>,
      isFetching: boolean,
      errors: Array<any>,
    }
  }
```

This is working mostly fine, my types are working, except for the main `storeKey` part. This is because the `createState` function takes the `entity.storeKey` as the key for the returned state, like so:

```js
export const createState = (entity) => {
  return {
    [`${entity.storeKey}`]: {
      byId: {},
      allIds: [],
      active: [],
      deleted: [],
      isFetching: false,
      errors: [],
    },
  }
}
```

So the whole state generation thing works fine, types are ok and everything, the problem comes when I'm trying to reference my state in a mutation for example. In my `mutations.ts` I want to be able to do something like

```js
export const mutations = {
  ...createMutations(provider), // My base mutations, typed fine
  ADD_PROVIDER_FILE(state: State, { id, file }: { id: number, file: any }) {
    state.entities.byId[id].files.push(file) // The problem is here "Property entity doesn't exist"
  },
  // More mutations...
}

export default mutations
```

TS does not recognize the fact that my `entities` key on the `state` object can be pretty much anything and is generated dynamically by my `createState` function, depending on a given `entity`'s `storeKey` attribute.

So my question is: **Is there a way to declare an interface for my `BaseState` that declares `storeKey` as an object with any name but still containing the right attributes and types inside ?**

What I've tried so far :

- `[key: string]` instead of `storeKey` as my key in `BaseState`
- Extracted the content of the `storeKey` object in a new interface and doing something like :

```
    interface BaseStateKeys {
      byId: any,
      allIds: Array<number>,
      active: Array<any>,
      deleted: Array<any>,
      isFetching: boolean,
      errors: Array<any>,
    }

    interface BaseState {
      [key: string]: BaseStateKeys
    }
```

None of this worked.

Anything clever I'm missing ? Thanks for help !